# Any idea why I'm getting the error "Column number must be between 1 and 16384"?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, closedxml

What my code is trying to accomplish is copying all the cells from one worksheet into another. It is  the simple block

```
// find the index of the first empty row and column in the dumped file
int m = 1; while ( !wb.Worksheet(3).Cell(m,1).IsEmpty() ) ++m; 
int n = 1; while ( !wb.Worksheet(3).Cell(1,n).IsEmpty() ) ++n;
// copy from dumped file into raw data file
for (int i = 1; i < m; ++i )
{
    for (int j = 1; i < n; ++j)
    {
        wb.Worksheet(1).Cell(i,j).Value = wb.Worksheet(3).Cell(i,j).Value;
    }
}
```

and somehow this is throwing the error

> Column number must be between 1 and 16384

Any idea why that could be? I don't see any infinite loops or anything like that.

Comment: You should log out the values of `m` and `n`.

Comment: @poke This is a web app, so it's hard to log values. Also, as a test, I set `n=4` and `m=4` and got the same error. Strange.

Comment: You could write the value into some specific cell. Anyway, do you get any more information which line throws that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things going on with this line of code.

```
for (int j = 1; i < n; ++j)
```

1. There is no limit on `j`; it will just just keep increasing while `i < n`. It should probably be:
         `for (int j = 1; j < n; ++j)`
2. This is most likely unrelated but `++j` increments *before* j is used. Use `j++` to increment *after* j is used. Your code could be written as
         `for (int j = 2; j < n; j++)`
         I'm not sure if you want the first iteration to start with j as 1 or 2.

Comment: Whoops ... type-o :(

Comment: re: *type-o* In the actual code or just in the question...?

Comment: In my code. I'm going to give you best answer for supplying a pair of eyes when mine were failing.

Comment: Wow, good catch on the condition there. Note that `++j` or `j++` doesn’t matter in this case as it will be executed as a separate statement after the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looping until you find an empty row or column. If it doesn't find one (seems unlikely) then it's definitely going to go past the boundaries.

What are you using? Is it interop? You could check for `Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` and `Worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count`. Depending on what you're trying to do you could possibly just copy and paste `Worksheet.UsedRange` instead of copying the values one cell at a time.